# How to create a file with content using debugfs in kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems

With this debugfs API I can create a file in /sys/kernel/debug/parent/name, but it's empty, no matter which data I put in `void *data` parameter

`struct dentry *debugfs_create_file(const char *name, mode_t mode, struct dentry *parent, void *data, struct file_operations *fops);`

According to [documentation](https://www.infradead.org/%7Emchehab/kernel_docs/filesystems/debugfs.html) we need to implement file_operations ourself to handle file open and write.
A snippet of code from mine:

```
static ssize_t myreader(struct file *fp, char __user *user_buffer, 
                                size_t count, loff_t *position) 
{ 
     return simple_read_from_buffer(user_buffer, count, position, ker_buf, len);
} 
 
static ssize_t mywriter(struct file *fp, const char __user *user_buffer, 
                                size_t count, loff_t *position) 
{ 
        if(count > len ) 
                return -EINVAL; 
  
        return simple_write_to_buffer(ker_buf, len, position, user_buffer, count); 
} 
 
static const struct file_operations fops_debug = { 
        .read = myreader, 
        .write = mywriter, 
}; 
 
static int __init init_debug(void) 
{ 
    dirret = debugfs_create_dir("dell", NULL); 
      
    fileret = debugfs_create_file("text", 0644, dirret, "HELLO WORLD", &fops_debug);
    debugfs_create_u64("number", 0644, dirret, &intvalue); 
 
    return (0); 
}
```

After installing this module to kernel, two files 'text' and 'number' will be created in the folder 'dell'. File 'number' contains the number I passed in as 'intvalue' as expected, but the other file 'text' is empty.
It's written in document that *data will be stored in the i_private field of the resulting inode structure*
My expectation: The string "HELLO WORLD" will be written in the file after module is loaded.

I think that the problem should be in the read and write operation functions. Is it possible to create a file with a particular content with the debugfs_create_file method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, whatever you are expecting from your code is correct but it is not going to produce the expected result. I believe there are other more efficient and correct ways of doing it, but to explain the current behavior:

- You are initializing data as content of file `text` but you are reading from buffer `ker_buf` in `user_buffer` instead of file pointer using `simple_read_from_buffer(user_buffer, count, position, ker_buf, len);`
- Similarly you are writing to `kern_buf` from `user_buffer` using `simple_write_to_buffer(ker_buf, len, position, user_buffer, count);`

With the existing code, if you want to achieve what you are trying to do, then you have to copy the string `"HELLO WORLD"` to `kern_buf` in `init_debug()`

Something like:

```c
strscpy(kern_buf, "HELLO WORLD", strlen("HELLO WORLD") + 1);
```

or in form of complete function:

```c
static int __init init_debug(void) 
{ 
    dirret = debugfs_create_dir("dell", NULL); 
      
    fileret = debugfs_create_file("text", 0644, dirret, NULL, &fops_debug);
    debugfs_create_u64("number", 0644, dirret, &intvalue);
    
    strscpy(kern_buf, "HELLO WORLD", strlen("HELLO WORLD") + 1);
    return (0); 
}
```

---

Edit:

Referred some online materials and found out that the `void *data` provided to `debugfs_create_file()` during initialization gets stored in the `i_private` field and can be later retrieved from the `i_private` field of the resulting `inode structure`.

The inode of the respective file can be fetched from `struct file *fp` which is the first argument of `read()` or `write()` operations.

The `struct inode` is a member of [`struct file`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L947) and `i_private` is a member of [`struct inode`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L702)

To fetch `void *data` provided during file creation via `debugfs_create_file()` in `read()` you can do something similar to as shown below:

```c
static ssize_t myreader(struct file *fp, char __user *user_buffer, 
                                size_t count, loff_t *position) 
{
    struct inode *l_inode = fp->f_inode;
    strscpy(user_buffer, (char *)l_inode->i_private, PAGE_SIZE);
    ...
    
}
```